# How do I fix the "Your NAND dump is probably incomplete" error on the Dolphin emulator?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii, emulation, dolphin-emulator

"*There must be a ticket for 00000001/00000002. Your NAND dump is probably incomplete.*" - This is the error message that appears when I try to open up a ROM on the Dolphin emulator.

What does this mean and how can I fix it so I can continue playing my game?

Comment: What happens if you disable panic handlers? Under Config, it should be within the Interface tab.

Comment: what is the version of your emulator?

Answer (score 5):

A NAND dump is a copy of the Wii's system files that are necessary to emulate games (roughly equivalent to BIOS dumps for PS1/2 emulation). It appears your dump is incomplete (apparently some games require a full dump while others do not).

The [Dolphin wiki](http://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Dumping_NAND) has this to say about dumping NAND memory from your Wii.

> **Dumping NAND with [BootMii](http://bootmii.org/)**
>
> To dump NAND with BootMii, you'll need:
> A homebrewed console with BootMii installed
> A SD card
>
> Access BootMii through the Homebrew Channel. Use a GameCube Controller or the Power and Reset buttons to navigate through the BootMii menus, as detailed here. Select Options (gears icon) on the far right. Select Backup NAND (Green arrow from chip to the SD card), and wait until it completes. Once completed, remove the SD card and put it into your system. You should see a file named NAND.bin on the SD Card. If you do, your NAND has been backed up.
>
> **Placing the NAND files into Dolphin**
>
> Use [NAND Tools](http://forums.dolphin-emu.org/attachment.php?aid=1383) to extract the files from NAND.bin. Make sure to back up any Dolphin files you wish, then place the NAND files into the User/Wii/ subdirectory. DO NOT replace the User/Wii/shared2/sys/SYSCONF file. Dolphin has its own, unique SYSCONF file, and overwriting it with the one from your NAND dump will confuse Dolphin.

Comment: Trivia: The name "NAND" comes from the [type of solid-state memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#NAND_flash) the Wii uses to store that system code/data.